# Github - Duplicate project '..' directory in parent preventing Pull or Clone

Tags: github

I pulled a repo down and something occured where I pulled a second copy of it into the folder, and it was named '..' (working on OSX).  I didn't notice it throughout the day, worked on the project parenting this rogue child clone, pushed it up.

Came home, can't pull it down on my Windows machine with this return in Bash:

`From https://github.com/<myname>/<myproject>
* branch master -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: cannot create directory at '<mydirectory>/ ../actions': No such file or directory.`

So, I've been experimenting with cloned masters on the remote side and test branches on this side, trying to figure out how I can impress removing this directory, but I can't pull it down, so that I have it on this machine, to delete it, because of the unaccepted naming convention, and merge attempts are just going to allow that folder to be there.

I also ran `git rm -r --cached myproject/..`, based off other posts I read. It showed stuff being deleted in Bash, but it didn't reflect web side, so I maybe don't understand that command that well.

So, that's where I'm at, writing a post.

Answer (score 0):

> It showed stuff being deleted in Bash, but it didn't reflect web side

That is expected since `git rm` is a local operation.
Try and commit, then push that deletion, to see if that does change the remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

I tried that method on other branches on the Windows machine, but then Git chose to merge the two branches without conflicts without deleting anything on the remote.

I went back to a Mac today and it was allowed to pull the '..' directory, and I was able to commit and push the deletion to the remote there.

So, if you make this mistake, don't expect a Windows machine to allow the operation and be able to clone from it to do the same thing.

It's an interesting difference that Mac allows the distinction and Windows doesn't.  It's understandable, since a lot of code reads `..` to move up a parent instead of attempting to access a directory with that syntax.